# SQL - trying to get what doesn't exist

Tags: sql, count, null

Two related tables -- tasks and activities. For every active task, there should be one related Open activity. Trying to find tasks with no Open activities. FYI, activity status includes Open, Completed, and Cancelled. Task status is Active and Inactive.

Relative newbie to SQL world, though have the basic principles.

Thought something along the lines of SELECT * from Tasks WHERE Status = Active AND the count of related Activities with Status of Open = 0, but I'm not sure how to translate that into SQL.

Have read a few posts here and elsewhere regarding temp tables and outer joins, but I couldn't work it out -- believe was for an audience slightly more advanced than me.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: How would you express "the count of related Activities with Status of Open" in SQL?

Comment: Hey Ricardo, can you share the table data along with the column names. It would help others understand better and help you

Comment: Now I have not seen your table yet but maybe you're trying to write this if it helps: `Select *
From Tasks
Where Status = Active AND Open = 0`

Comment: Maybe just SELECT * from Task WHERE Status = Active AND  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Activities WHERE Activity.Task_Id = Task.Id)

Comment: Wow, the number and speed of answers is amazing -- a great and active community! Thanks Nicholas and mishsx; Between these and Gordon's below, I believe we'll be off to the races.

Answer (score 1):

> Trying to find tasks with no Open activities.

Use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from tasks t
where not exists (select 1
                  from activities a
                  where a.task_id = t.task_id and
                        a.status = 'open'
                 );
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon -- I believe this will do exactly what we need. As I mentioned above, pleasantly surprised  with the community activity -- will make good use of it in the future, I'm sure, and perhaps one day contribute an answer or two. Thanks again to all!